# Is there a way to make a before_save conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a before_save in a rails app conditional, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
before_save method_call_to_run if self.related_model.some_method_that_returns_t_or_f?
```

If the 'some_method_that_returns_t_or_f' returns true, I want it to run the method before it saves the object otherwise I just want it to ignore the before_save.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can use :if

```
before_save do_something, :if => Proc.new {|model| model.some_boolean_attr_or_method }
```

or simply

```
before_save do_something, :if => some_condition
```

EDIT:

for a quick reference, there's an excellent guide about this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks

Answer (score 15):

**Rails 5**

I've had success defining a private method which contains the boolean logic and then passing it as a symbol (that last part seems like a requirement):

```
before_save do_something, if: :private_boolean_method?
```

I also recently found out you can simply pass a block (took me a while to figure out the syntax):

```
before_save do_something, if: -> { condition == "met" }
```