# Rails 5 - how to negate a method call on a before_save callback conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, before-save

In my Template model I have this callback:

```
  before_save :set_status, if: :is_template?

  private

  def is_template?
    return self.template_type == 'template'
  end
```

How can I change it so that it only fires when the template_type is NOT 'template'?

I tried these:

```
1 before_save :set_status, if: !:is_template?
2 before_save :set_status, if: !(:is_template?)
```

but they both cause 'method `before_save` not found' error.

Having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409932/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-before-save-conditional), I also tried this:

```
  before_save :set_status, if: Proc.new {|model| !model.is_template? }
```

But that seems overkill for such a simple case.

Do I really have to write another method `:is_not_template?` for this to work?

Comment: Try `before_save :set_status, unless: :is_template?` ;)

Comment: @DivXZero So obvious when you see it. I keep forgetting about unless!  Thank you so much! Please post as the answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `before_save :set_status, unless: :is_template?` ;)